# How to fill the columns that contain references from other tables

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I am re-writing a MS Access data base in SQL.

Create a database "Pizza delivery" with fields:

1. Order date
2. delivery address
3. Phone number of the buyer
4. Couriers name
5. Quantity
6. Name of the pizza
   The database should consist of 3 linked tables: in separate tables need to allocate a list of managers and a list of pizza names.

In MS Access by referencing the key of `Pizza` and `Couriers`, I would have two columns in `Orders` displaying the possible options from those  two referenced tables. Then when creating a row in Order I would just choose one of the options displayed for Pizza and Couriers. Thats one order.

I dont understand how to make that link in SQL. Should I use `FOREIGN KEY` or just a `REFERENCES`.
When filling up the table Orders, what should I write in Pizza and Couriers? again in MS Access the options are displayed, what is the procedure in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Pizza(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Pizza VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Courier(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CourierName CHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

    CREATE TABLE Orders(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY ,
    [Time] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Address] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Telephone CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    CourierID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Courier(ID),
    PizzaID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Pizza(ID),
    Quantity SMALLINT NOT NULL
    );



INSERT INTO Pizza
VALUES ('New York'),
        ('Napolitana'),
        ('Hawaiian'),
        ('Peperoni');

INSERT INTO Courier
VALUES ('Peter Parker'),
('Patrick Bateman'),
('Pedro Picapiedra');


INSERT INTO Courier
VALUES ('Peter Parker'),
('Patrick Bateman'),
('Pedro Picapiedra');
```

PS. It is a simple example, to have a glance of SQL. This code doesnt have to consider every possible real scenario

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a front-end that can show you options like that. You would need to use some tool, such as MS Access or another GUI to connect to it. `REFERENCES` is just short-hand for `FOREIGN KEY...` see linked answer. Side note: it's a bit odd to have a column called `Time` which is of type `DATE` you probably want `DATETIME2`